# replacing xsd:choice in regularly updated XSD's

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

Is there a simple (XSLT?), preferably automated, way to alter an xsd:choice construct in an XSD file to a definition without the choice construct. For example, I get an XSD that contains the following segment:

```
<xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
   <xsd:element name="ExistingBuild" type="ExistingBuild" nillable="false"/>
   <xsd:element name="NewBuild" type="NewBuild" nillable="false"/>
</xsd:choice>
```

This XSD needs to be imported in an application that doesn't support the choice construct. I have manually changed the XSD to have the segment defined as follows:

```
<xsd:element name="ExistingBuild" type="ExistingBuild" nillable="false" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="NewBuild" type="NewBuild" nillable="false" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

The resulting XSD can be imported correctly and serves the purpose. So manually I can change this.

However, this XSD will get updated regularly in the future and I would need to manually alter it every time a new version is delivered. To prevent manual errors I am looking to automate this conversion. Is XSLT a possible solution for this, and how would I define such an XSLT solution?

Thanks in advance for any help in this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that hard to write an XSLT to remove the `xsd:choice` element

Start with the identity template (which handles the things you don't want to update)

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Add a template to ignore `xsd:choice`

```
<xsl:template match="xsd:choice">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

Then add a template to process the child `xsd:elements`

```
<xsl:template match="xsd:choice/xsd:element">
  <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="{../@maxOccurs}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
  </xsd:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Putting this all together gives this...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsd="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xsd:choice">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xsd:choice/xsd:element">
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="{../@maxOccurs}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    </xsd:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it in action with an imcomplete schema at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2Di

Comment: Wow, I wasn't expecting responses to come in so quickly and detailed, thanks. I will try that and let you know if it worked.